# reading JSON data from url which contains multiple nested arrays

Tags: java, json

1st program

```
package bll.sap;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import utility.PropertyUtility;

public class GetActiveData 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sapURL = "";
        String transactionSapURL="";
        try {


            sapURL = PropertyUtility.getSapURL();
            transactionSapURL = PropertyUtility.getTransactionSapURL();

            //Get Summary Data
            //SapDataSync sapDataSync = new SapDataSync();
            SapDataSync sapDataSync = new SapDataSync();

            //sapDataSync.readTransactionJsonFromUrl(sapURL+"E13F42EC5E38");
            sapDataSync.readTransactionJsonFromUrl("http://localhost/uatpw/ActiveTransaction?isx=E13F5AFA45CE");


            } 
        catch(MalformedURLException me)
        {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }   
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

2nd program

```
package bll.sap;


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONException;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import utility.Utility;

import com.google.code.morphia.Datastore;
import com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.Uri;

import dal.GetMorphiaDB;

    public class SapDataSync 
    {

        private void saveSapTransaction(List<TransactionUnit> sapTransaction){
            GetMorphiaDB morphia;
            try {
                morphia = GetMorphiaDB.getInstance();
                Datastore ds = morphia.getDs();
                ds.save(sapTransaction);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void createSapTransaction(String transactionJson)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(transactionJson);

            JSONArray transactionUnits = jsonObj.getJSONArray("TRANSACTION");

            //System.out.println("transactionUnits="+transactionUnits);

            List<ActiveUnit> transactionList = new ArrayList<ActiveUnit>();

            for(int i = 0; i < transactionUnits.size() ; i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsn = transactionUnits.getJSONObject(i);


                ActiveUnit transactionUnit = new ActiveUnit
                (
                        jsn.getString("listEditions"),
                        jsn.getString("listPackage"),
                        jsn.getString("referenceID")

                );



                //System.out.println("transactionUnit ="+transactionUnit);
                transactionList.add(transactionUnit);
                //System.out.println("transactionList ="+transactionList);  
            }

            //System.out.println(transactionList.size());
            if (transactionList.size() > 0) {
                //saveSapTransaction(transactionList);
            }

        }

        public void readTransactionJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException 
        {

            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            try 
            {
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              int cp;
              while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) 
              {
                sb.append((char) cp);

              }


              createSapTransaction(sb.toString());
            } 
            finally 
            {
              is.close();
            }
         }



    }
```

3rd Program

```
package bll.sap;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id;

@Entity("SapTransaction")
public class ActiveUnit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String listEditions;
    private String listPackage;
    private String referenceID;
    private List<ActiveUnit> listEdition;
    public ActiveUnit() {
    }
    public ActiveUnit(String listEdtions, String listPackage,String referenceID) {
        this.listEditions = listEdtions;
        this.listPackage = listPackage;
        this.referenceID = referenceID;

    }

    public String getreferenceID() {
        return referenceID;
    }

    public void setreferenceID(String referenceID) {
        this.referenceID = referenceID;
    }

    public String getListEditions() {
        return listEditions;
    }

    public void setListEditions(String listEditions) {
        this.listEditions = listEditions;
    }

    public String getListPackage() {
        return listPackage;
    }

    public void setListPackage(String listPackage) {
        this.listPackage = listPackage;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        String unit = "{ " +"listEditions: "  + this.listEditions+
                            ",listPackage: "+ this.listPackage+ 
                            ",referenceID: "  + this.referenceID+
                      "}";
        return unit;
    }
}
```

AFTER running 1 st program
I am getting data in JSON format from that url as below.

```
{
"TRANSACTION":[
{ 
"listEditions": [
{
"adRoute":"B",
"listInsertion":[
    {
        "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},

{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
}
],

listPackage: 
[
{

listEditions: [
{
"adRoute":"B",
"listInsertion":[
    {
        "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},

{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
},
{
"adRoute":"A",
"listInsertion":[
    {   "color":0,"colorType":"All Colour","fromDate":"26/06/2013","height":25,"page":2,"pagePosition":2,"pagePositionType":"Regular            Page","size":823,"sizeDimention":"32.9x25","toDate":"26/06/2013","width":32.9,"pubDate":""
    }
    ]
}
]
}],

"referenceID": "E13F42EC5E38" 
}
]
}
```

NOW the question is how do I read all key and values from that JSON data which has inner arrays inside.
I can read data from that TRANSACTION Array.
but further if i want to read data from that listEditions array and an array listInsertion which inside listEditions array, then it creates problem for me.
however I tried some ways but in vein.
please help.
current code is only for reading data from TRANSACTION Array.
I am not getting how do I code for to read data from other arrays.
I tried to read it but it says it's not an array , it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backing object model which could be constucted using the JSON string, you can use google's Gson API, which will seamlessly parse the JSON string and create objects for you.